# Django: updating a column, saved in a variable name

Tags: django, django-models

I have a variable say, column_name.
I want to update a column whose name is saved in the variable column_name.

For example:
I have a table with columns as: a, b, c, ..., z.
column_name store either of these values. So I want to update that particular column which is saved in the variable column_name.

Thanks
Anuj

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Model.objects.update(**{column_name: "my new value"})
```

See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2921893/16361

Comment: I want to update a particular row, which I will get via some condition: team = Teams.objects.get(user=username). What I generally do is team.column_name='my new value' and then team.save(). But this will obviously wont work. And what I could see is that kwargs work only in function calls. So how does I implement my scenario?

Comment: `setattr(team, column_name, "my new value")`. And: [docs on `setattr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr)

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you could also do `Team.objects.filter(id=team.id).update(**{column_name: "my new value"})`.